# Insert value of list into different column to mysql Python

Tags: python, mysql, list

I have list instead some value. I want to split the value of the list and insert into different column.

```
def insert_data(daftar):
query = "INSERT INTO citra(img_source,fitur_0,fitur_1,fitur_2,fitur_3,fitur_4,fitur_5) " \
        "VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)" 
try:
    db_config = read_db_config()
    conn = MySQLConnection(**db_config)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.executemany(query, daftar)
    conn.commit()
except Error as e:
    print('Error:', e)
finally:
    cursor.close()
    conn.close() 

def main():
for x in range(len(list)):
    list[x]
result = str(list).strip('[]')
daftar = [(file,result)] 
print daftar
insert_data(daftar)

if __name__ == '__main__':
main()
```

when I compile the code

```
[('E:/py/BatikTest/B43_1.jpg', '0, 0, 0, 92, 57, 5')]
```

I got error

> ('Error:', ProgrammingError(-1, 'Not enough parameters for the SQL
>   statement', None))

I think the value still in one list. Is possible to split the value and insert into different column?

Answer (score 0):

> [('E:/py/BatikTest/B43_1.jpg', **'0, 0, 0, 92, 57, 5'**)]

Remove quotes. Right code is:

```
[('E:/py/BatikTest/B43_1.jpg', 0, 0, 0, 92, 57, 5)]
```

Comment: Looking at the insert_data function it might even need to be without the brackets... e.g. `('E:/py/BatikTest/B43_1.jpg', 0, 0, 0, 92, 57, 5)`

Comment: yeah actually I've tried to removed the single quotes using